# Wordpress REST API cannot post comments

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to post comments to my posts using the Wordpress JSON API but I keep getting an error.

Heres what I have done:

I have added the 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments' function

```
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );
```

Then went to the URL

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=192&author_email=mytestemail@gmail.com&author_name=TestName&content=ThisIsTestContent
```

But it just returns the error:

```
{"code":"rest_forbidden_param","message":"Query parameter not permitted: author_email","data":{"status":401}}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you're entering that URL into your browser's address bar that won't work. You need to send a [POST request](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) instead.

Comment: Show me your code or you are using different approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You have to create a endpoint for comment.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'mycomment/v1', 'comment/(?P<post_id>\d+)',array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'post_comment'
      ));
});
```

Then the post_comment in callback will point it to another function to create another function for your logic. In this call back function, you can add your comment using wp_insert_comment().

```
function post_comment($request) {
// Your code here
}
```

Enjoy!